# Possible to have separate "namespace" in one file?

Tags: c, namespaces

Is it possible to block access to variables and functions as you would by having a separate file but in the same file? Like how in javascript you would use anonymous functions.

Comment: Why would you need this? The file is aware of itself, so just use a prefix to denote namespace or name the functions differently in the first place.

Comment: @Dave - Curiosity and convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have hiding in the sense that the declaration of the static function or static variable can follow after the function it is hiding from. Using a macro, you can hack your way into hiding a function or variable after it has been defined.

```
static void foo () { /* ... */ }
static int g_hidden_from_foo;
static void bar () { /* can use foo() */ }
#define foo foo_is_now_private
/* effectively hides foo */
```

This may satisfy your curiosity, but I can't say it is convenient (or wise).

If you are open to using compiler extensions, GCC has [nested functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html), which is more or less similar to anonymous functions.

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly possible in C.  The unit of code in C is the translation unit, which is the fancy way of saying the file you're editing (plus header files).

Any code in a particular translation unit can "see" any of the preceding declarations and definitions.  There is no way to change that in standard C.  You can use macros or naming tricks to hide identifiers, but you can't outright stop access, especially not in a readable/convenient way.

If you're willing to use separate files you can simply avoid putting a declaration in your public header file to make the data "hidden" and can make function declarations as static to make them completely inaccessible to other translation units.

If you use C++ instead then you can get a bit further by using classes with protected and private members, as C++ protection semantics are per-class rather than per-translation-unit.